# how to find out a result set by which column ? if we write 3 columns in where clause with OR Operators on single table

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a database table. That table has 4 columns. In 3 columns members(values) want to access the 4th column value.

So here i don't want to write same query for every member. I want to write only single query. So is it possible with single query? If possible how I can know which column has given those result set?

```
select 4thcolumn from tablename where lstcolumn=?1 or 2ndcolumn=?2 or 3rdcolumn=?3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `OR` is a solution (but that requires you to repeat the parameter three times):

```
SELECT col4 FROM mytable col1 =:myvalue OR col2 =:myvalue OR col3 = :myvalue;
```

One solution to shorten the query (and pass a unique parameter) is to use `IN`:

```
SELECT col4 FROM mytable WHERE :myvalue IN (col1, col2, col3)
```

If you want to know which column matched, then this gets longer. In MySQL you can do:

```
SELECT 
    col4,
    col1 = :myvalue is_col1,
    col2 = :myvalue is_col2,
    col3 = :myvalue is_col3 
FROM mytable 
WHERE :myvalue IN (col1, col2, col3)
```

This adds three columns in the result set: `is_col1`, `is_col2`, `is_col3`; the column(s) that matched will have value `1`, other(s) will show `0`.

Comment: Really Thanks to you for provided answer to my question. In case if write like this "SELECT col4 FROM mytable WHERE :myvalue IN (col1, col2, col3)"---- how can i say who gave that  result set. i mean col1 or col2 or col3.